# Help Hibernate Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: power-management, hibernate

I've add this following code to 
`/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla`

```
[Enable hibernate by default]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

When i choose to hibernate, the pc doesn't shutdown but i can see the text in the image in the link...

[image]

Help me please..I need to hibernate my computer..
Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to include the model # of your laptop, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`nouveau` is the built-in (open source) driver for Nvidia graphics cards. What the error is telling you is that *nouveau* had trouble getting the Nvidia card to go into the power state necessary for the system to hibernate.

Two possible solutions:

1. Try the binary Nvidia drivers instead (go to System Settings...Additional Drivers); if that doesn't work try the different versions of Nvidia drivers that may have worked for others with your specific card series/model (google, search askubuntu, etc.)
2. [See this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/146599/58612) on how to try an alternative hibernation method (TuxOnIce) which is reported to be compatible with a wider variety of hardware. Of course, it may or may not work....

Answer (score 0):

You can check my post on this http://arecordon.blogspot.com.ar/2013/08/ubuntu-enabling-hibernation.html

You might need to update GRUB. There's also a test that you can run to make sure the hibernation works Ok.

Please, let me know if it worked.